# What is the right way to draw on canvas the square with alpha opactity?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Why the square in this example is remaining visible? What I'm doing wrong?

Example:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");

ctx.canvas.width = 500;
ctx.canvas.height = 500;

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 20, 1)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)";
ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 300, 300);

for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
 ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 20, 0.2)";
 ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 300, 300);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

How I understand, after 5 iterraations of cycle, the square have to dissapear, but this not happens after 10. How to calculate the opacity by the right way?

There is a new example:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
var background = "#000236";

ctx.canvas.width = 500;
ctx.canvas.height = 500;

ctx.fillStyle = background;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

var i = 0;
var inter = setInterval(function()
{

  for (let j = 0; j < 14; j++)
  {
   ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)";
 ctx.fillRect(10 + j * 40, i * 10, 20, 20);
  }
  
  ctx.save();
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
  ctx.fillStyle = background;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  ctx.restore();
  
  i++;
 
  if (i >= 50)
  {
    i = 0;
  }
}, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see below the opacity is not `cumulative` (I think the term is multiplicative but I'm not a visuals guy). What I mean is that after two iteration of the function below you do not have opacity `0.4`. It's a mathematical process that approaches it's maximum but will not reach it. You are using `0.2` each time but what you see is only a little less of the color beneath. Think of layering pieces of colored cellophane over your background, each time it becomes a little dimmer but you wont really stop seeing your background.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");

ctx.canvas.width = 500;
ctx.canvas.height = 500;

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 20, 1)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)";
ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 300, 300);

let count = 30;

function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 20, 0.2)";
    console.log(ctx.fillStyle);
    ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 300, 300);
    count--;
    if (count) {
        setTimeout(draw, 500);
    }
}

draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

To get the result you want, this would probably be a better solution:

```js
    var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");

    ctx.canvas.width = 500;
    ctx.canvas.height = 500;

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 20, 1)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)";
    ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 300, 300);

    let count = 0;
    let iterations = 5;

    function draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 20, " + count / iterations + ")";
        console.log(ctx.fillStyle);
        ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 300, 300);
        count++;
        if (count <= iterations) {
            setTimeout(draw, 500);
        }
    }

    draw();
```

```html
    <canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but you solution is unsuitable, becouse I want to make some kind of animations, and I don't want to fill everithing. Better look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/profesor08/vmp22seq/
There I use global opacity instead of setting opacity of fillStyle, but result is the same.